# Getting data from AWS API for transit gateway

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I try to get BytesOut metric for my transit gateway with the code below:

```
async getCloudWatchMetrics({ startTime, endTime = new Date() }: { startTime: Date; endTime?: Date }): Promise<MetricDataResults> {
    const params = {
      StartTime: startTime,
      EndTime: endTime,
      MetricDataQueries: [
        {
          Id: "bytesout0",
          Label: "BytesOut",
          MetricStat: {
            Metric: {
              Namespace: "AWS/TransitGateway",
              MetricName: "BytesOut",
              Dimensions: [
                {
                  Name: "TransitGateway",
                  Value: "XXXXXXX",
                },
              ],
            },
            Period: 300,
            Stat: "Average",
          },
        },
      ],
    };
    const res = await this.CloudWatch.getMetricData(params).promise();

    return res.MetricDataResults;
  }
```

It works fine. I have one AWS key per region but as I understand there can be multiple transit gateways per region and in that case, how can I get this metric for a specific transit gateway in that region?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Value field in the request is the ID of the transit gateway so It will return data for that specific transit gateway.